# Setting up users to use the batch system on LSF Spectrum

Tags: ibm-cloud, user-permissions, system-administration, lsf

I have set up a new LSF Spectrum cluster on IBM cloud, using the default CentOS 7 image. I can run jobs as the default `lsfadmin` user. My question is: how do I set up other users to do the same?

Looking at the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spectrum-lsf/10.1.0?topic=queues-making-your-cluster-available-users), it looks like I just have to add the `profile.lsf` to the end of a user's `.bashrc` file. Thus:

- I create a new user with `useradd`
- I add the contents of `profile.lsf` to the end of the new user's `.bashrc`
- I log in as the new user and submit a job with `bsub`.
- The job is submitted, but is stuck in the `PEND` state, with the message:

```
PENDING REASONS:
 Unable to determine user account for execution;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: A user account of the same name and UID needs to exist on the execution host.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Michael. Do you know how one is supposed to set up users so that this happens? Does Spectrum LSF use LDAP? Is it some custom list of authorised users somewhere that the compute nodes use?

The cluster compute nodes are created and destroyed as needed, and are set up so one cannot easily get into them, so adding users manually seems very impractical.

Comment: LSF will just use the standard OS interface (`getpwname`, `getpwuid`) to determine if the account exists on the execution host.  You can use whatever mechanism you want to make sure that the account exists.  canned password file, ldap.  I think LSF also supports user account mapping. https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/example-how-configure-user-account-mapping-lsfhosts-mixed-cluster

Comment: Possibly one other option that might be useful to you. If you use LSF MultiCluster, you can map users or user group to users when  job is forwarded to another cluster.  https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spectrum-lsf/10.1.0?topic=files-lsbusers

Comment: Thank you. IBM support gave me the same answers as above (that I needed users with the same UID on head and compute nodes), and were able to help me set up a user mapping. They also suggested LDAP as a better long-term solution.